# Simple optimization 3D plot

Tags: plotting

Because this is such a simple example I am not going to explain the calculations. I am strictly wondering why I do get errors when plotting it.

```
Plot3D[(Subscript[x, 1] - 2)^2 + (Subscript[x, 2] - 1)^2, {Subscript[
x, 1], -10, 10}, {Subscript[x, 2], -10, 10}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, 
 Subscript[x, 1]^2 - Subscript[x, 2] <= 
 0 && -Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 2] + 2 <= 2]]
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works without error in MMA 10.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot3D[(Subscript[x, 1] - 2)^2 + (Subscript[x, 2] - 1)^2,
        {Subscript[x, 1], -10, 10}, {Subscript[x, 2], -10, 10}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 - y <= 0 && -x - y + 2 <= 2]]
```

[image]

Note the error message generated by:

```
Function[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, 
 Subscript[x, 1]^2 - Subscript[x, 2] <= 
   0 && -Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 2] + 2 <= 2]
```

> [image]

See also the explanation and examples in the docs on `Function::flpar`.

Update:

> *What If I only want to mark out that area but not remove the rest if the function...*

```
Plot3D[{ConditionalExpression[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2, Not[x^2 - y <= 0 && -x - y + 2 <= 2]], 
  ConditionalExpression[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2, x^2 - y <= 0 && -x - y + 2 <= 2]},
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: What If I only want to mark out that area but not remove the rest if the function.  By for Eg. The patch that this plot is given being a different colour than the rest.

Comment: @ALEXANDER, please see the update.